# Android: Modern emoji support by upgrading appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, emoji, android-fonts

I am trying to enable modern emoji support in my app for Android 10 and below.
For this I have upgraded `AppCompat` to version 1.4.0 following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2).

However, modern emojis still don't show up. I have gone through and verified [instructions](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2#appcompat-displays-tofu) as well.

Then I tried the second approach - by directly including emoji2 dependency and using `androidx.emoji2.widget.EmojiTextView` instead of `AppCompatEditText` in my layout. This doesn't work on its own.
But, it works when I explicitly disable `EmojiCompatInitialize`  from manifest and initialize `EmojiCompat` in my app , i.e.:

In manifest:

```
         <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
           <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                tools:node="remove"/>
        </provider>
```

In my activity `onCreate()`:

```
        val fontRequest = FontRequest(
            "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
            "com.google.android.gms",
            "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
            R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
        )
        val config = context?.let { FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(it, fontRequest) }
        if (config != null) {
            EmojiCompat.init(config)
        }
```

But this is not the recommended way as per the docs as it requires custom initialization and using explicit `EmojiTextView` in layout files.

Could someone please help me understand why upgrading only `AppCompat` is not working for me?

Comment: Did you find any solution @FurElise? I'm looking for the same question. 
The document says the google play version code should be higher than 211200000. Maybe that is the point I don't know but It doesn't show new emoji on the android 6 emulator.